# VS2022 swagger document generation on build

Tags: visual-studio, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator, .net-7.0

I am trying in VS2022 using .net 7 to auto build an open-api (swagger) specification, that I want to wire later in connected services. My problem is that the file is not being created.

This is my swagger configuration:

```
public static void ConfigureSwagger(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        if (builder == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
        }

        var appSettings = builder.Configuration.GetObjectFromConfigSection<AppSettings>("AppSettings");


        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(x =>
        {
            x.SwaggerDoc(appSettings.SwaggerPublicGroupAPI, new OpenApiInfo { Title = "aov.org public API", Version = appSettings.SwaggerPublicGroupAPI });
            x.CustomOperationIds(e => $"{e.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["action"]}");

            // This code allow you to use XML-comments
            string xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            string xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            if (File.Exists(xmlPath))
            {
                x.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            }

            x.AddSecurityDefinition
            (
                "Bearer",
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Description = "Please enter token into the field",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
                }
            );
        });
    }

    public static void ConfigureSwagger(this WebApplication webApp)
    {
        if (webApp is null)
            return;

        var appSettings = webApp.Configuration.GetObjectFromConfigSection<AppSettings>("AppSettings");

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        webApp.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        webApp.UseSwaggerUI(x =>
        {
            x.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{appSettings.SwaggerPublicGroupAPI}/swagger.json", "aov.org public API");
        });
    }
```

The appSettings are coming from appSettings.json and have the following entries:

```
  "AppSettings": {
    "SwaggerPublicGroupAPI": "public",
    "VersionAPI": "1.0"
  }
```

In the WebAPI project I added the following lines:

```
<Target Name="OpenAPI" AfterTargets="Build" Condition="$(Configuration)=='Debug'">
        <Exec Command="echo Generating OprnAPI." />
        <Exec Command="dotnet swagger tofile --output ./_open-api.json $(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll public"
              ContinueOnError="true" />
    </Target>
```

The project builds, but in the output window am getting a strange error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.)
1> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
1>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
1>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
1>   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
1>   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
1>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
1>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.InternalOpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
1>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
1>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<ExistsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
1>--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
1>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<ExistsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
1>--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
1>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass30_0`2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
1>--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
1>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.ExistsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.MigrateAsync(String targetMigration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\temp\amazonsofvolleyball\Backend.WebAPI\Program.cs:line 83
1>   at Program.<Main>(String[] args)
1>   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
1>   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
1>   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.HostingApplication.GetServiceProvider(Assembly assembly) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\HostingApplication.cs:line 81
1>   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.GetServiceProvider(Assembly startupAssembly) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\Program.cs:line 152
1>   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.<>c.<Main>b__0_4(IDictionary`2 namedArgs) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\Program.cs:line 82
1>   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\CommandRunner.cs:line 68
1>   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\CommandRunner.cs:line 59
1>   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\Program.cs:line 121
1>C:\temp\amazonsofvolleyball\Backend.WebAPI\Backend.WebAPI.csproj(5,3): warning MSB3073: The command "dotnet swagger tofile --output ./_open-api.json bin\Debug\net7.0\Backend.WebAPI.dll public" exited with code -532462766.
```

Any ideas?
thnx

Comment: I have the same error, any solutions?